# How to close Java scanner when scanner is referenced in a string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I currently have a scanner that scans the entire contents of a file and prints the data that is read to a text area, sort of like an open function. My problem is that the method that i have used (as well as being the only one i know of) requires a file to be created and then deleted, however this file that has been created cannot be deleted as it is being used by the process of the scanner and I do not know how to close the scanner as it has been defined in a string. It is probarably a simple solution, but it has been eluding me for some time. Thank you in advance. Here is my code:

```
int returnVal = fc.showDialog(this,
                                  "Open");

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();

        try {
            new FileEncryptor("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding",fullPath).decrypt();


                String content = new Scanner(new File(fullPath + ".dec")).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

                jTextArea1.setText(content);

                //close scanner here to delete file

                File n = new File(fullPath + ".dec");
                System.out.println(n);
                n.delete();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


    } else {

    }

    //Reset the file chooser for the next time it's shown.
    fc.setSelectedFile(null);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it has been defined in a string"? Just call `content.close()`. That won't affect any of the data you've already read.

Comment: You don't need to close the Scanner since there are no Scanner instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it into more lines.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fullPath + ".dec"));
String content = null;
try {
   content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
} finally {
   scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer and well explained with examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference an object in a String, esp not a Scanner.

The String is a copy of the data you want so closing the Scanner won't alter the String which is immutable (unchangeable)

What you want to do is hold onto the Scanner so you can close it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fullPath + ".dec")).useDelimiter("\\Z");
String content = scanner.nextLine();

scanner.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, your comment and explanation were both informative and valid, however i cannot end the scanner with a new line but have used the info you provided to find something that works.

Answer (score 0):

You're losing the handle to the scanner.

Try something like:

```
            Scanner contentScanner = new Scanner(new File(fullPath + ".dec"));
            String content = contentScanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            contentScanner.close();
```